# What is wrong with using e.g.?

Tags: writing-style

I am currently using [devd/Academic-Writing-Check](https://github.com/devd/Academic-Writing-Check) for my master thesis in computer science. One thing it complains about is the usage of `e.g.`. What is wrong with that?

For example, I wrote:

```
1. In the case of many classes (e.g. 1000~classes of ImageNet) ...
2. This threshold can either be set automatically (e.g. such that 10% of all pairs are above the threshold) or semi-automatically ...
3. \item Color space (e.g. RGB, HSV)
```

Comment: I've heard at least one source say something like, "No one studies Latin anymore, so younger people don't know what that means". I personally say screw that advice.

Comment: Without reading the text, it's difficult to say: maybe you misused _e.g._ in place of _i.e._, or you didn't put a comma after _e.g._, or simply the authors of that app thought that using such kind of abbreviations is not nice.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Thank you, I think it might be the missing `,`. I've added 3 examples to my question. To me, a `,` after `e.g.` looks really weird.

Comment: Who knows? Ask whoever wrote that software, don't just accept their views as absolute truth...

Comment: It's definitely the missing `,` after `e.g.`.

Comment: The regex in the `fixAbbr` method (in `checkwriting` file) definitely wants a comma after *e.g.* https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g4cB.png

Comment: There is an "English Language and Usage" Stack Exchange site which is perhaps a better fit for your question than this site. That said, (1) in my opinion what you wrote is definitely fine as it is, and it would also be fine with a comma after e.g. in each case; (2) grammar advice given by a regex string matcher can be useful, but should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: Are you using LaTeX (seems like you might be with `\item` and a `~` for (presumably) a non-breaking space, but then you have `10%` not `10\%`)? If you are using LaTeX and this tool which detects "typographical errors" is designed to check for LaTeX errors then `e.g. ` is wrong if you're not using French spacing. It should be `e.g.\ ` otherwise you will get a sentence-ending space after the `.` not an inter-word space. In fact you might even want to use `~` after e.g. as I'm not sure I'd like my line to break after e.g.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: It's short for "example given" for non-Latin speakers :P

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to the English usage stack exchange.

Comment: @Laurel while I think it might be closed as a dupe, I think it is potentially a good dupe, so am going to migrate it anyways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I commented, a possible cause is that of the missing comma after *e.g.*; Pam Peters in her *Cambridge guide to English usage* says:

> The punctuation before and after **e.g.** has long been the subject of prescription. A comma used to be considered necessary after it, and is still usual, according to the *Chicago Manual* (2003). But most style guides now dispense with the following comma, and simply emphasize having one before it.

So, some still suggest the usage of a comma after *e.g.* Actually, whenever I didn't put a comma after *e.g.* in a paper, the typesetter added it.

Indeed, this is easy to check: add a few commas here and there and see what happens!

Comment: I do not know. _All_ of my British co-authors _remove_ the comma after e.g.

Comment: @PsySp Punctuation in British English and American English are different.  Of course there's a larger problem that people think the rules they learned are strict rules everyone has to follow, even if the rules they learned were actually just guidelines.